# Image to fit container on Rotate

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When a image is rotated via javascript, the image doesn't readjust fill the parent container.

How can the image be made to readjust to the parent container?

I understand the height now controls the width and the width the height. Although readjusting the height and width still seems to squash the image.

I've create a bootstrap demo to show the issue.

http://www.bootply.com/9ClazvIz6x

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `max-width: initial;` So it will override bootstrap's style

```
image.css({
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + imageRotation + 'deg)',
    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + imageRotation + 'deg)',
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + imageRotation + 'deg)',
    'transform': 'rotate(' + imageRotation + 'deg)',
    'height': height * imageRatio,
    'maxWidth': 'initial'
});
```

Comment: This works great for keeping the image at the right size and aspect ratio. Although it hangs outside the container. Any idea how to keep the image inside the container? I've updated with your changes: http://www.bootply.com/BmV9cEr23s